# Easy way to mock a WCF service?

Tags: .net, wcf, unit-testing, mocking

I've got an app which is using a WCF service. Now I'd like to add unit tests to the app.

For some cases I need to mock the WCF service, since getting the desired behaviour from the service sometimes is tough (e.g. service throws special exceptions).

I could add yet another interface to the wcf client, but this seems a bit silly, since the client calls already are using an interface.

Is there an easy way to mock a WCF service? Easier than creating another interface layer and redirecting every single WCF call inside it?

Edit: Most of the answers seem not to know much about WCF service using, so some clarification:
To use a WCF service from a ViewModel, I have to manage the connection something like this:

```
ChannelFactory<IMyWcfService> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMyWcfService>("");
IMyWcfService proxy = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
proxy.CallMyStuff();
proxy.Close();
```

I can't just pass the ViewModel the proxy to the WCF, since the connection needs to be opened and closed for every transaction. For this reason using RhinoMock/NMock would not work, since they need a ViewModel which gets the proxy as a parameter, which can't be done like this if you use WCF.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why can't you use something like [NMock2](http://nmock2.sourceforge.net/) to mock the `IMyWcfService` interfaces directly?

If you need to be able to create new instances on the fly, use the Factory to hide the `ChannelFactory<IMyWcfService>` from the client. This way you can replace the factory, providing the client one which creates mocks instead of real proxies.

Comment: please provide an example

Comment: what is the ChannelFactory?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: The ChannelFactory is a WCF class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can you `Moq` mocking framework. Based on the example that you have provided:

```
ChannelFactory<IMyWcfService> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMyWcfService>("");
IMyWcfService proxy = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
proxy.CallMyStuff();
proxy.Close();
```

Here is how a mocking implementation will look like:

```
Mock<IMyWcfServiceChannel> channelMock = new Mock<IMyWcfServiceChannel>(MockBehavior.Strict);
channelMock
    .Setup(c => c.CallMyStuff())
    .Returns("");

string myStuff = channelMock.Object.CallMyStuff();
```

After you have added a proxy for the `WCF` service - you should have a `channel` interface available to you, called `IMyWcfServiceChannel`.

Depending on the return type of service method you are calling - you can set just about any output. In the example above I used `string` type as an example.

In order to use the above solution more efficiently you might want to create 2 constructors for the business layer like so:

```
public class Example1
{
    IMyWcfServiceChannel _client;

    public Example1()
    {
        var factory = new ChannelFactory<IMyWcfServiceChannel>("binding");
        _client = factory.CreateChannel();
    }

    public Example1(IMyWcfServiceChannel client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public string CallMyStuff()
    {
        return _client.CallMyStuff();
    }
}
```

So on the `prod` you use parameter-less constructor. In `unit` tests you use parameter-full constructor and pass mock to it (`channelMock.Object`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use any mocking framework like RhinoMocks or NMock, to mock out the interface contract, so if your service implemented IMyService then you could use a mocking framework to set expectations on the method calls on that interface.  If you are not familiar with this concept then you can simply create a stand-in object that implements IMyService but pretends to be the real service during your testing.  This way when the methods are called they are called on your stand-in object and you can have your stand-in return whatever you want it to.

Comment: Using RhinoMock/NMock I would need to open the connection to the WCF service, pass the proxy to the ViewModel, and close it after use. Since WCF connections usually have a short timeout, and should be opened and closed for every transaction, this is a no-go.

Comment: In other words: you can't use RhinoMock/NMock to mock an WCF interface. At least not that I know of, if you know a way, please share it.

Answer (score 1):

I am using FakeItEasy, which doesn't allow for mocking of OperationContext because it's a sealed class.  Add dependency injection into the mix, and you've got yourself a straight-up nightmare.  I've spent a week trying to figure this stuff out, and here's what I finally came up with . . . you're going to create a couple of `ServiceHost`'s, and then they're going to talk to each other and run all your code in between.

#1 Create a class that inherits from `ClientBase<IMyWcfService>`:

```
public class MyWcfServiceClient : ClientBase<IMyWcfService>, IMyWcfService
{
    public MyWcfServiceClient(string address)
        : base(new WebHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(address))
    {
        this.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
    }

    public void CallMyStuff()
    {
        using (new OperationContextScope(this.InnerChannel))
        {
            base.Channel.CallMyStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

#2 Create a "calling service" that will call this method.  First, create an interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyWcfCallingService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void CallCallMyStuff();
}
```

Then create the "calling service" that implements this interface:

```
public class MyWcfCallingService : IMyWcfCallingService
{
    static MyWcfServiceClient _client = new MyWcfServiceClient("http://localhost:8008");
    // ^^^ This "http://localhost:8008" is the address where
    // your actual service is going to "live" in your unit test        

    public void CallCallMyStuff()
    {
        _client.CallMyStuff();
    }
}
```

#3 Instantiate your actual service in the unit test:

```
var myService = new MyWcfService(_someMockedDependency, _someOtherMockedDependency);
```

#4 Create the two `ServiceHost`'s that are going to talk to one another, and call your service:

```
var restHost = new WebServiceHost(myService, new Uri("http://localhost:8008"));
// ^^^ Make sure the URL here matches the URL you used in Step #2

var behavior = restHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceBehaviorAttribute>();
behavior.InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single;
// ^^^ If you're using dependency injection with mocked dependencies 
// to create your myService object, this is muy importante

restHost.Open();

var clientHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyWcfCallingService), new Uri("http://localhost:80"));
// ^^^ use some other address here, different from the one you used for the service itself
clientHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyWcfCallingService), new BasicHttpBinding(), string.Empty);
clientHost.Open();

var factory = new ChannelFactory<IMyWcfCallingService>(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:80"));
// ^^^ this should match the url for the clienthost
var proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
proxy.CallCallMyStuff();
```

Damn WCF all to hell!  I never appreciated WebApi so much as when I started having to dig through legacy WCF code.