# Can we have a Unit test project dedicated only to WCF in Visual Studios 2013?

Tags: wcf, unit-testing, automated-tests

Just wanted to know whether we can have a Unit Test Project dedicated to a WCF Solution or not ? I know this might be a Generic question but I couldn't get specific answer to it even though I searched through various blogs and websites. Please suggest.

Comment: what do you mean 'dedicated to a WCF solution'?  Do you want to unit test a WCF service? Maybe an example of what you mean might be good?

Comment: Hi Sam,We have created a WCF Service. We want to create a Unit Test Project for this Solution. Please suggest.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154735/testing-a-wcf-web-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes its possible to unit test WCF services. The options are:

- create classes which do all of the work which are separate from the WCF service. Unit test these classes in isolation. Make your service a thin wrapper which calls these classes.
- test directly with the WCF service class without it being hosted (a bit like [this example](http://geekswithblogs.net/blaird/archive/2010/03/16/basic-wcf-unit-testing.aspx))
- Have the unit tests host the WCF service in process and then call the services via named pipes or similar (see the [console example here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee939340.aspx) for details of how to self-host). When you self host you should start the service in the test setup or the test fixture setup and then destroy it in the corresponding teardown.