# How to mock WebOperationContext for unit testing?

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing, rest, weboperationcontext

I am trying to get a unit test(more of an integration test) written for the `GetAwesomeResultsAsXml()` for the following WCF Rest Service.
How do I deal with the `WebOperationContext` mocking aspect?
What would be the best approach?

```
public class AwesomeRestService : AwesomeRestServiceBase, IAwesomeRestService
    {
        public AwesomeSearchResults<AwesomeProductBase> GetAwesomeResultsAsXml()
        {
            return GetResults();
        }

        private static AwesomeSearchResults<AwesomeProductBase> GetResults()
        {
            var searchContext = AwesomeSearchContext
                               .Parse(WebOperationContext.Current);
            ..............
            ..............
            ..............
        }


    }

[ServiceContract]
    public interface IAwesomeRestService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        BodyStyle =  WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            UriTemplate = "/search/xml")]
        AwesomeQueryResults<AwesomeProductBase> GetAwesomeResultsAsXml();


    }







public class AwesomeSearchContext
        {
            ................
            ................
            ................
             public static AwesomeSearchContext Parse 
                                           (WebOperationContext operationContext)
            {
                return WebOperationContext.Current != null ? new     
 AwesomeSearchContext(operationContext.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.QueryParameters) : null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: what do you want your test do do?

Answer (score 10):

I met the same problem. I want to unit test a WCF service function (for IOauth2 interface as below example) without any IIS. This is the code snippet for the preparation.

```
// Prepare WebOperationContext
var factory = new ChannelFactory<IOauth2>(
    new WebHttpBinding(),
    new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:80"));

OperationContext.Current = new OperationContext(factory.CreateChannel() as IContextChannel);
Debug.Assert(WebOperationContext.Current != null);
```

Comment: What NuGet package is IOauth2 in?

Answer (score 3):

I followed Sanjay's answer, and try the MS fake framework,

First of all, you have to `open "Solution Explorer > your test project > Reference"` => `right-click the  "System.ServiceModel.Web"` => `press "add Fakes Assembly"`

### Reference:

```
using Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes;
using System.ServiceModel.Web.Fakes;
```

### Sample:

```
using (ShimsContext.Create())
{
    var response = new ShimOutgoingWebResponseContext();
    var request = new ShimIncomingWebRequestContext();

    var ctx_hd = new WebHeaderCollection();
    ctx_hd.Add("myCustomHeader", "XXXX");
    request.HeadersGet = () => ctx_hd;

    var ctx = new ShimWebOperationContext
    {
        OutgoingResponseGet = () => response,
        IncomingRequestGet = () => request
    };
    ShimWebOperationContext.CurrentGet = () => ctx;

    //Test your code here...
}
```

and now you can get the WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers["myCustomHeader"] in your WCF service code now.

More about MS Fakes framework on MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549176.aspx

Comment: ShimsContext.Create() is giving NullReference exception. `StackTrace:    at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.TraceProfilerInstrumentationProvider.TraceProfilerMethods.ResolveProfilerPath()
   at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.TraceProfilerInstrumentationProvider.TraceProfilerMethods..cctor()`

Comment: How about trying to run VS as admin and run your test again? I got it from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44147376/unable-to-use-microsoft-fakes-in-vs2015-enterprise-cor-profiler-missing

Comment: System.TypeInitializationException - {"The type initializer for 'TraceProfilerMethods' threw an exception."}

Comment: Microsoft Fakes is unfortunately only available to Premium editions of Visual Studio. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18339061/1077279.

Answer (score 2):

A common approach to this is mocking tool like moq (https://code.google.com/p/moq/) or rhinomocks.

As they don't allow you to mock static members you would need to wrap the call to webcontext.current.   Here is an example of wrapping a static mmember and testing with moq: [Mock static property with moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416362/mock-static-property-with-moq)

Answer (score 1):

Likely overkill if you are not already using the MS Fakes framework, but if you are this works for me.

```
using (ShimsContext.Create())
        {

            var response = new ShimOutgoingWebResponseContext();
            var ctx = new ShimWebOperationContext
            {
                OutgoingResponseGet = () => response
            };

            ShimWebOperationContext.CurrentGet = () => ctx;

            try
            {
                ParameterInspector.BeforeCall("operationName", new string[]{"some_argument"} );
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Assert.IsNull(e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you tell me where these (ShimOutgoingWebResponseContext and ShimWebOperationContext) are located?  My code is not finding them and I am trying to determine which framework class(es) to include.  I am already including the Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.

Answer (score 0):

Create a client for your service, and then handle the OperationContext within the client:

```
public class AwesomeRestServiceClient : ClientBase<IAwesomeRestService>, IAwesomeRestService
{
    public class AwesomeRestServiceClient(string address)
        : base(new WebHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(address))
    {   
        this.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
    }

    public AwesomeSearchResults<AwesomeProductBase> GetAwesomeResultsAsXml()
    {
        using (new OperationContextScope(this.InnerChannel))
        {
            return base.Channel.GetAwesomeResultsAsXml();
        }
    }
}
```

For further info on how to use this, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406955/easy-way-to-mock-a-wcf-service/67677474#67677474).