# Add Fakes Assembly option missing

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vs-unit-testing-framework, microsoft-fakes

I'm trying to get the `Microsoft Fakes` up and running in a Unit test project that I've set up in my solution.

For some reason the `Add Fakes Assembly` option is missing which means I can't create mockups of assemblies. And since this is the only alternative to add the `Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes` assembly I can't use the `Shim` functionality either.

I've recently installed **`Visual Studio 2012 Professional`** and installed **update 3** and this is the first go in `Visual Studio 2012`. And I haven't changed any settings. Although I have installed `ReSharper`, could this be the culprit?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Both Visual Studio 2019 and 2017 only has this feature in the Enterprise edition (they both have 3 main editions: Community, Professional and Enterprise.)

If you'd only need the `Stub` functionality, then you could simply pick other mocking frameworks. You mention `Shim`s, which is an advanced functionality. I have heard some mock frameworks which can be close to that advanced.

I've heard of Prig (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sug.Prig-OpenSourceAlternativetoMicrosoftFakes), but I haven't ever tried it. @neaGaze says it's not supported in VS 2017.

The newest screenshot of the feature matrix's (https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/compare/) related section:

[image]

---

Visual Studio 2017 feature matrix - only Enterprise offers Fakes:

[image]

---

Visual Studio 2015: Microsoft Fakes is available in Premium Edition and up.

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2919309-provide-microsoft-fakes-with-all-visual-studio-edi

Comment: I ended up installing Premium Edition and there it was. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It became available to Premium editions as well with Update 2.

Comment: Yeah. Totally annoying. I hope that they can flesh this out.  Make the framework available for all SKUs and also have a clear cut scenario for test project types that are below .Net 4.5

Comment: I see another uservoice item, which is older but not completed: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2216195-include-pex-and-moles-with-all-visual-studio-editi

Comment: What about VS2017. How do I do this now?

Comment: unlike `VS2017`, in `VS2019` - only the [Enterprise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/isolating-code-under-test-with-microsoft-fakes?view=vs-2019) version got it, and `Premium` does **not**.

Comment: Thanks for the update @itsho . I'll edit the answer because that was the situation for VS 2017 as well, only VS 2015 had it in the Premium

Comment: Prig is not supported for VS2017